# How would I go about reading audio from my headset? This clearly did not work

Tags: java, audio

All my audio on pc goes to Game except discord/etc going to Chat.

So basically I'm just wondering why when I pass the correct audio format to my TargetDataLine It doesn't work???

I'm new to audio in general along with TargetDataLine.. Completely unfamiliar with this class.

Wouldn't using a BufferedIN/OUTReader be better with handling this?

Have not yet attempted.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class CaptureFromSoundCard
{

    boolean stopCapture = false;
    AudioFormat audioFormat;
    TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;
    BufferedInputStream in = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CaptureFromSoundCard tx = new CaptureFromSoundCard();
        tx.captureAudio();
    }

    private void captureAudio()
    {
        try
        {

            Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
            audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);
            Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[1]);
            System.out.println(mixer.getMixerInfo()); //1 is target 48,000hz, 16bit, stereo(2ch), signed, nobigEndian
            targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);
            targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
            targetDataLine.start();
            Thread captureThread = new CaptureThread();
            captureThread.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private AudioFormat getAudioFormat()
    {
        float sampleRate = 48000.0F;
        int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
        int channels = 2;
        boolean signed = true;
        boolean bigEndian = false;

        return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed, bigEndian);
    }

    class CaptureThread extends Thread
    {
        byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

        public void run()
        {
            stopCapture = false;
            try
            {
                while (!stopCapture)
                {
                    int cnt = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length);
                    out.write(tempBuffer);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Not that familiar with handling sound.**

```
run:
Headphones (5- Arctis Pro Wireless Game), version Unknown Version
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface TargetDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Output Above
[image: Device Properties]
Mind you this is NetBeans IDE 8.2 I'm working in.

Comment: Haven't actually done anything with the audio yet clearly. Was making sure this would work before going too far into the idea I was gonna use this for

Comment: If I'm not mistaken I think windows is denying me access to read from it?

Comment: I've only used TargetDataLine to get data incoming from a microphone or for obtaining internally generated data to be used for writing to file. I've used SourceDataLine to output audio to the OS for playback. There have been numerous posts asking about intercepting or capturing audio that the OS is sending to speakers or headphones, but I've never seen an answer. Are you trying to write the code for game audio to output to headphones or intercept the output of an external game?

Comment: Well the idea behind this was 1. Capture the audio in live feed to headset, 2. somehow interpret the incoming to listen for an audio cue (what shazam does for instance), 3. Do something if the cue comes up. And yeah i've been looking into it but no real answers for intercepting the audio being played to my headset, though someone did mention a dll work around that i would really like to avoid if i could.

Comment: It's all for a "Shiny Counter" program i'm wanting to make for like pokemon/temtem. I could take a few different approaches i just thought the sound approach was a good test for myself. Visual cues from like a capture or something could also work but that's more toward AI/DeepLearning than i would like to go lol.

Comment: IDK if it can be done, taking sound from, say, a line going to the headphones. If the sound were going out the speakers, then the microphone could potentially capture that if it were loud enough. Maybe what you are proposing is doable. Maybe you need to tap the line closer to the source, e.g., create something that is some sort of intermediary between the application and the OS. I really don't know if that is viable either. Sorry can't help more.